# CASE right after WITH in Neo4j and Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In Cypher, when I have

```
...  
WITH a, b, c  
CASE  
WHEN d IS NULL  
THEN RETURN ...  
ELSE  
MATCH ...  
RETURN ...  
END
```

I get "Invalid input 'S': expected 'l/L'". How do I need to format it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `CASE` statement is an expression that evaluates to some value, which then is typically aliased to a variable. It is not control flow and you cannot have a `RETURN` within a `CASE` statement. For example:

```
MATCH (a:Person)
WITH a.name AS name,
CASE WHEN a.age > 55 THEN True ELSE False END AS seniorCitizen
RETURN name, seniorCitizen
```

In that example `seniorCitizen` is a boolean where the value depends on if a.age is greater than 55 or not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Then, is there any command in Cypher to change the control flow?

Comment: No, not really. There are some workarounds, such as using [`FOREACH`](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2016/10/30/neo4j-create-dynamic-relationship-type/). What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I found another workaround to change the flow so I do not need this. Thanks.

Comment: @Afshin A good idea: to share your solution in addition to the main post.